# ggplot not showing inside ipython notebook output area, rather popping up

Tags: python, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I'm using IPython notebooks to save my results and perhaps to share code including graphics. I am using ggplot right now. But I cannot get ggplot to plot inside the notebook output area. It always gives me a pop-up window that shows the plot. I don't know how to save it along with the notebook easily. Is there something I need to configure to make that happen? "%matplotlib inline" I saw in a ggplot tutorial that below code should do it. What am I missing?

My code:

```
plot = ggplot(my_dataframe, aes("x")) + geom_histogram()
print plot
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer elsewhere. It worked like a charm!

%pylab inline